# ng-repeat to get values from an array of json from backend

Tags: html, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, ruby-on-rails-5

I am having an array of json values in my backend ruby file `business_integrations`.

Code for json values is

```
def self.all
    @_all ||= [
      {
        name: 'Google Analytics',
        logo: 'ga.png',
        category: 'Web Analytics',
        link: '/businesses/%{business_id}/google_analytics_settings_change'
      },
      {
        name: 'Google Search Console',
        logo: 'search_console.png',
        category: '',
        link: '/businesses/%{business_id}/google_search_console_settings_change'
      },
    ].map do |integration_hash|
      BusinessIntegration.new(integration_hash)
    end
```

My controller is

```
app.controller('IntegrationCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
  'ContactIntegrationService', '$mdDialog',
  function($scope, $routeParams, ContactIntegrationService, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.business_id = $routeParams.business_id;
    $scope.tracker_id = $routeParams.id;
    $scope.integrationList = {};
    $scope.config_id = {};
    $scope.enable = [];
    var _getListElement = function(suggestion, integrationList) {
      var suggestionkey = _.keys(suggestion);
      var integrationkey = _.keys(integrationList);
      var item = _.intersection(suggestionkey, integrationkey);
      var suggestionList = _.omit($scope.suggestion, item);
      $scope.empty = _.isEmpty(suggestionList);
    };
  }
]);
```

For now, I have hardcoded the values into view as

```
<div class="list-group-item">{ 'ng-show': 'filter.all || filter.webAnalytics' }
  <div class="row-picture">
    <img />{:alt => "icon", :src => "#{image_path 'integrations/google_analytics.png'}"}</div>
  <div class="row-content">
    <div class="least-content">
      <a class="btn btn-raised btn-warning mt-xs n">{'ng-href': "{{free_service ? '' : '/businesses/'+ current_business+'/google_analytics_settings_change'}}",
            'ng-class': "{'btn-success': !biz.google_analytics_id, 'btn-warning': biz.google_analytics_id}", 'ng-disabled': 'free_service'}
              {{biz.google_analytics_id ? 'Manage':'Connect'}}</a>
    </div>
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Google Analytics</h4>
  </div>
  <hr class="mg-bt" />
</div>
```

Can I display the json array in my view using ng-repeat? How can I display the json array? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, You can display json Array using ng-repeat, please follow the link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat, you still face any problem, then gve me dummy json structure, So that i can answer more clearly. Thanks, Kusum

Comment: @KusumKushwaha My json is as given above. I am a beginner to angularjs. my json is in my ruby file. How can I call it in my controller and view?

Comment: Provide full sample of data and html code also, then I can help you for AngularJs part. Also if your problem is just client side (AngularJs), just put these parts. not server side!

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee the html code is too big (440 lines). I want to loop the json content in the view